# Can't convert number to Int C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, int

I'm trying to make a small application. It gets an ID in a server response, but it's in string format. I need to convert it to `int`, but it doesn't seem to work. That ID is for example `76561198078450726`. `Int.TryParse` returns `0`.

Other methods doesn't work either. Do you have any Idea, whats the problem?

Edit: Thanks a lot for your helpful answers. I don't know, how I could miss that. Thanks!

Comment: `TryParse` never returns `0`, it returns `true` or `false` as @Mark already mentions. What you actually mean is that its `out`-param might be `0`, which is absoluetely vallid.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I meant..

Answer (score 5):

That's a really big number. Int only goes to `2147483647`.

Use `long` or take a look at `System.Numerics.BigInteger` to go even bigger: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx

Edit:
Also, `int.TryParse` returns `true` or `false` and **that** is what you should be checking, not if the `out` value is 0. Because `int i; int.TryParse("0", out i);` is also completely valid.

Answer (score 3):

76561198078450726 is far outside the range of `int` (which is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647), use `long` instead:

```
if (long.TryParse(value, out myValue)) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since [`int.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue) is `2147483647`, this value is *too* large for an 32-bit signed integer. I would suggest to parse it to [`long`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.int64) instead.

```
long l = long.Parse("76561198078450726");
```

Answer (score 2):

`Int32.MaxValue` is 2,147,483,647. When TryParse fails it returns 0.

Try `long.TryParse()`

[image]

[Reference](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpNumericDataTypes.aspx)